# Clickonce change auto update to manual update for existing installations

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce deployment for a specific application with many existing users. Currently, the deployment manifest specifies "auto update on startup" option.

I would like to change the deployment manifest so it would specify that auto update is turned off and I could manually trigger update for my application.

What bothers me is the question if current deployment can be updated without users reinstalling the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: yes, switching auto update off in the manifest does not break existing client installations, manual update strategy can be used afterwards and no reinstall is required.

(at least that worked with .NET 4.0 clickonce deployed application)